# laravel's validator doesnt return input fields

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

problems with returning inputs. after form submitted, if validator fails it doesnt return 'old' inputs. here's my controller

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'user_rate' => 'required|integer|between:1,5',
        'user_comment' => 'required',
    ], [
        "user_rate.integer" => trans('errors.rate-required'),
        "user_rate.between" => trans('errors.rate-required'),
        "user_rate.required" => trans('errors.rate-required'),
        "user_comment.required" => trans('errors.com-required'),

    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput($request->input());
        //return redirect()->back()->with(Input::all());
    }
```

i have tried several ways(also $request->flash(), but it doesnt return 'old' inputs

Comment: Please try to redirect to a named route and with Input, something like
`return redirect('post/create')
                        ->withErrors($validator)
                        ->withInput();`
[Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#other-validation-approaches)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your controller

```
public function someFunction(Request $request)
{
    //Validation Logic

    if($v->fails())
    {
        return redirect()->back()->withInput();
    }
}
```

In your view

```
<input type="text" name="some_name" value="{{old('some_name')}}">
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Don't pass any arguments to the withInput function

```
 if ($validator->fails()) {
    return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
    //return redirect()->back()->with(Input::all());
 }
```

and how are you getting the old inputs in your form?